# Wordpress query_posts Loop inside of another loop, results not working out

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to build a query that will grab information from two different post_types. I have Q&A Videos and Law Firms. These are Setup through Custom Post Type Manager (CCTM) via Wordpress Plugin. I have the Law Firms in a different post type for when Law Firms signup. But at some point, we have people asking questions under the Q&A Video Section, and the Law Firm will answer those questions and when they do, they will select their name from the custom field dropdown for Law Firm Selection.

There is a code almost identical to this one that works great in the Single-QAVideos.php page. But it actually has a unique page identifier. The code below does not have a unique page identifier, as I am trying to build this to show the most recent answers. But for some reason, this Loop inside a Loop is not working correctly. If I run this, I get that it forgets the first query listing 5 per page. This query will only run and show one. I need it to show as many as the first query will allow which is 5. If you see any errors in coding below, as far as syntax, you can let me know. I don't have access to the actual query right now and I have retyped a similar query below. Can anyone help with this?

```
 <?php

 //Retrieve a List of (5) Q&A Videos 
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'qavideos'
 );
 query_posts( $args );

 //Start Q&A Video Loop
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      //Get the title of each
      $qatitle = get_the_title();

      //Get the Law Firm ID from the Law Firm Selection Dropdown Custom Field
      $lawfirmid = get_custom_field('lawfirmselection');

      //Start New Query - get law firm information associated with this post
       $argstwo = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'lawfirm',
         'meta_query' = array(
            'key' => 'ID',
          'value' => $lawfirmid
       )
      );
      query_posts( $argstwo );


      while (have_posts()) : the_post();

     $lawfirmname = get_the_title();
     $lawfirmstate = get_custom_field('state');

      endwhile;
      wp_reset_query();

//Start Displaying The Information Grabbed and Placed in Variables
 ?>
     <div class="lawinfo">
       <h1><?php echo $qatitle; ?></h1>
         <ul>
                <li><?php echo $lawfirmname; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $lawfirmstate; ?></li>

        </ul>
     </div>
 <?php

 endwhile;
 wp_reset_query();

 ?>
```

UPDATED WORKING CODE FOR INNER LOOP:

```
  //Search Post Type Law Firms to Get Law Firm Info
  $argse  =  array('page_id' => $lawid, 'post_type' => 'law_firms');

   $posts_array = get_posts( $argse );
   foreach($posts_array as $postn)  
    {
      $lname = $postn->post_title;
      $lstate  = get_post_meta($lawid, 'state', true);
     }
```

Comment: I actually forgot to add that to this script fore it is in the original script that way as well. I edited this Question. I also changed the name of the query variable to $argtwo, which is the inner query. Please relook at it. I am only getting one result and should get 5.

Comment: Have you tried using `get_posts()` instead of calling `query_posts()`? The later will modify the main loop

Comment: No I have not.  I will definitely try it in the morning when I am able to get access to the script again.

Comment: Does `lawfirmid` contain more than one value?

Comment: No it only contains the value of the ID of the lawfirm itself. I have used the same query on a single.php page and it works great! But that is if I have requested the page string from the URL and then pull the Q&A Video post using that one singluar post ID. This query is to retrieve 5 posts and it is not working.

Comment: I still think the problem is that you modify the main loop using `query_posts()`, try setting up a new query object using either `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query()`, then your second loop would look something like `while($query2->have_posts()): $query2->the_posts();`

Comment: get_posts() Worked! Thank you! I had to re-code the get_posts section since it doesn't work the same as query_posts(). But It worked like a charm! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code for the Inner Loop

```
  //Search Post Type Law Firms to Get Law Firm Info
  $argse  =  array('page_id' => $lawid, 'post_type' => 'law_firms');

   $posts_array = get_posts( $argse );
   foreach($posts_array as $postn)  
    {
      $lname = $postn->post_title;
      $lstate  = get_post_meta($lawid, 'state', true);
     }
```